# Not able to select an element which is declared as unselectable="on" for the code mentioned below

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I tired using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-dark-toolbar-small fa fa-plus')]")).click();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.id("button-1069-btnIconEl")).click();
```

But i am still getting no such element found exception. 
Please find the HTML in comment section

Comment: <span id="button-1069-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-dark-toolbar-small fa fa-plus " style=""></span>

Comment: Check if the element is inside `<iframe>` tag, and switch to it if it does. You can also try adding implicit or explicit wait.

Comment: Why do you want to click on an element with `unselectable='on'`? Share the relevant _HTML_

Comment: @DebanjanB i want to select that button given in the 'id'

Comment: @guy i tried Thread.sleep(5000); also implicit wait

Comment: Since another attribute (role) says it's for "presentation" I'm guessing that it's not a real button, and therefore non-functional, and non-clickable.  You say you want to select it.  Does it click manually?